# Assign controls to a property in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, collections, controls

Hej all,

I wonder if it's possible to assign more than one control to a property in XAML.

Say I have 2 controls in my XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="_Btn1 Content="Button 1" />
<Button x:Name="_Btn2 Content="Button 2" />

<local:MyControl x:Name="_MyCtrl" Controls="{what goes here?}" />
```

Or should I declare my control as a container control and put all controls inside it, like so:

```
<local:MyControl x:Name="_MyCtrl">
    <Button x:Name="_Btn1 Content="Button 1" />
    <Button x:Name="_Btn2 Content="Button 2" />
</local:MyControl>
```

Thnx in advance!

Grtz,
Dwi

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you make **MyControl** inherit **ItemsControl**.

Then this

```
<local:MyControl x:Name="_MyCtrl">
   <Button x:Name="_Btn1 Content="Button 1" />
    <Button x:Name="_Btn2 Content="Button 2" />
</local:MyControl>
```

will work and this

```
<local:MyControl x:Name="_MyCtrl" ItemsSource="ViewModelorControlCollection" />
```

will work too.

The ViewModelorControlCollection can be defined in your ViewModel or as a static resource in your xaml.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you're gonna do. Usually you'd simply define a `DataTemplate` instead.

```
<local:MyControl x:Name="_MyCtrl">
    <local:MyControl.ControlsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="Button 1" />
                <Button x:Name="btn2" Content="Button 2" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:MyControl.ControlsTemplate>
</local:MyControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need some kind of container. This can be a simple list or a specialized collection. Whatever you use in your control.

```
<local:MyControl>
    <local:MyControl.Controls>
        <ControlCollection> <!-- or whatever -->
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
        </ControlCollection>
    </local:MyControl.Controls>
</local:MyControl>
```

If you use a `Panel` or similar classes, you don't need to specify the `ControlCollection` explicitly. You then can define the controls like with e.g. the `StackPanel`.